# How to replicate basic configuration tasks?

Tags: configuration

*(This might be off-topic and/or not answerable, but I want to ask anyway.)*

Recently, I am managing a lot of VPS server with Linux for my personal and professional projects.

However, I am kind of tired by the repetitive tasks. Let's say I have to do the following after installation of a VPS

- add some users, add them to sudoers
- install the basic needed packages from apt-get
- find out that the package X is not in the basic repository, so I add some repositories
- do some basic configuration, both as a *root* and as a user, copy-pasting some stuff from the internet to some files and see what sticks
- finally start coding

Is there any way to automate the whole process? Basically to "seal" the whole configuration, so I can then do all this in somehow more simplier way.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the tip! That's actually the same question I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is an example of "configuration management". As you might expect, many other people have also had the same questions as you. The general class of software that performs this function is called [configuration management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software). Some popular examples are:

- [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/)
- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
- [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/)

Comment: I assumed I am not alone who does that :) Thanks for the tips. I will have a look at some of them.